# Nested Iterator loops for collision cause IllegalStateException

Tags: java, iterator, illegalstateexception

I have a game where a tank shoots shell of ammunition. My goal with this part of the code is to check if they collide with a "collision" tile and if so remove it and the tile.

The code looks like this and is checked every 1/60 of a second:

```
Iterator<Shot> iterator = shots.iterator();
        
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            
            Shot tempShot = iterator.next();
            tempShot.moveShot();
            
            Iterator<Tile> tileIterator = tiles.iterator();
            while(tileIterator.hasNext()) {
                Tile tile = tileIterator.next();
                if(tile.getHitbox().intersects(tempShot.getHitbox()) && tile.isHardObject()) {
                    tileIterator.remove();
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
            
            
            

        }
```

I somehow get the error: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException**. I predict this is happening due to the **if statement** but I don't really know how to prevent it from happening as I just learnt what the **"Iterator"** class did. I found out how to write the code above through links such as [this](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2018/01/concurrentmodificationexception-while-removing-elements-from-ArrayList-in-loop-Java-solution.html)

**Visualisation:**

The **GIF** below displays how it looks like. The shot hits the stone and it  then prints the error in the console. It should however remove the shot and the  tile.

[image: Tank shoots]

**What have I tried?**

If I remove **"iterator.remove"** it will result in no errors. The tiles will disappear still, but that is due to me having **"tileIterator.remove()"** in the code. Only when removing the ammo does the "error" happen. This makes me believe that there is something weird going on inside that if statement. Also, sometimes it seems to work and sometimes it doesn't..

**Stack trace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(ArrayList.java:979)
at com.dubstepzedd.tankgame.entities.Player.fire(Player.java:159)
at com.dubstepzedd.tankgame.entities.Player.tick(Player.java:53)
at com.dubstepzedd.tankgame.Application.tick(Application.java:65)
at com.dubstepzedd.tankgame.GameLoop.loop(GameLoop.java:63)
at com.dubstepzedd.tankgame.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:37)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
at com.dubstepzedd.tankgame.GameLoop.main(GameLoop.java:104)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: @Joni I added it :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We need to see variable declarations and initializations. Be sure to provide enough code that we can copy/paste it and run it ourselves.

Comment: I will do it as fast as I can :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Iterator.remove` method throws this exception if you have already removed the item. Given the structure of the code, it seems most likely that the exception came from `iterator.remove()`, meaning you've already removed the current item from `shots` and are trying to remove it again.

I don't know what this code is supposed to do, but perhaps breaking out of the inner loop so that you move on to the next item from `shots` is the right thing.

```
if (tile.getHitbox().intersects(tempShot.getHitbox()) && tile.isHardObject()) {
    tileIterator.remove();
    iterator.remove();
    break; // get next item from shots iterator
}
```

Comment: I was thinking something like that! If you remove items in a for loop and you get an error, it most likely is due to the item already being removed. I was however more thinking of doing "Iterator.next()" again but I didn't want to skip an item.. I totally didn't think of "break". And I feel so dumb. It worked, I tried the game and fired 15 shots and I haven't had an error yet atleast :) Thanks!

Comment: `iterator.next()` would also work, but you have to check if there is a next item. That would become ugly

Comment: I thought the same. It would just be way to complex for such a simple problem. Thanks again!